# I want to use JQuery when scrolling up or down using the mouse wheel or the side bar. The function that works automatically is stopped

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

iam new in js and jquery ,I have a function called scrollChatToBottom that scrolls down within 10 seconds

```
        function scrollChatToBottom() {

          if (isScrollingEnabled && !isScrolling) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
            console.log(x);
          }
        }

        scrollChatToBottom();
```

I want when I scroll up, the scrollChatToBottom function will be stopped from executing if I scroll with the mouse wheel or the sidebar.

here are full code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container" style="overflow: auto;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: aqua;">
            <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
            <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
            <h1>ghnghgh</h1>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100vh; background-color: rgb(132, 0, 255);"></div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var isScrollingEnabled = true;
        var isScrolling = false; 
        var x = 1;
        function scrollChatToBottom() {

          if (isScrollingEnabled && !isScrolling) {
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 10000);
            console.log(x);
          }
        }

        scrollChatToBottom();



        window.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event) {
          if (event.wheelDelta < 0) {
            x = 5;
            // التمرير لأسفل
            isScrollingEnabled = false;
            console.log(x);
          
            console.log('Scrolling down'); 
          } else {
            x = 5;
            console.log(x);
            isScrollingEnabled = false;
            console.log('Scrolling up');
          }

          isScrolling = true;
          setTimeout(function() {
            isScrolling = false;
            isScrollingEnabled = true; 
          }, 100);
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I created an functio that tracks the movement of the mouse weal, but it did not work

so i dont know what is the problem

Comment: You are creating a function called `scrollChatToBottom` which is called once and the jQuery `animate` function you call in it has nothing to do with any of your flags. If you want the current animation to stop, then use [jQuery's .stop](https://api.jquery.com/stop/).